# What are the performance consequences of encryption in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: performance, sql-server-2008, encryption

If you had a table that had 100,000,000 email addresses (example) and you want to store them securely but you don't want to take a huge hit with performance when you retrieve them, how would you go about storing them?

Comment: why don't you test it and see?

Comment: 100,000,000 email addresses would make for a great spam campaign - I'd store them in /dev/null. Perfect obscurity...

Answer (score 0):

Encryption algorithms are designed to be fast. If you have decided that encrypting your data is important (and personal information such as email address *is* important as @Marc B pointed out) then the question becomes "which algorithm has the right performance for my use case?"

I'd suggest you look at how much throughput you are expecting and test it. Use an industry standard algorithm and see if it meets your needs. Whatever you do, don't roll your own encryption. Crypto is **hard** to get right so trust the experts.

I'd suggest you start with AES/CBC/PKCS5. Store the ciphertext as a blob in the database. Key storage is always tricky and has been discussed on StackOverflow a fair bit so with any luck you can get advice on that aspect fairly easily. If you get sufficient throughput with that algorithm then you're done. If not, look around for a faster algorithm. I recommend http://bouncycastle.org as a good crypto library. It has a bunch of algorithms implemented so you can experiment and find one that meets your needs.

Did I mention that you shouldn't roll your own encryption? Good.